# how do you express habits by using past tenses?

Tags: tense

what's the difference between these two sentences:

> 1- I played football for 3 years
> 2- I was playing football for 3 years

Comment: Native speakers don't say "I was playing football for 3 years."

Comment: It sounds as though you literally played for three years without stopping!

Comment: why doesn't it sound as I repeatedly played for 3 years?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, *simple past*, it implies nothing about the *present*. You still might be playing football... or not.

In the second case, [past continuous](http://englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html), it implies something happened afterwards; e.g., "I was playing football *when I was injured*." It does not make as much sense by itself or with, "for three years."

You might use the [present perfect tense](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) here, e.g., "I *have been playing* football for 3 years," which implies you have played it for three years *and continue to do so*.